# jquery: remove text from select

Tags: jquery

I have the following html code:

```
<select class="select">
<option value="EUR"> EUR - Euro </option>
<option value="USD"> USD - United States Dollar </option>
<option value="AED"> AED - United Arab Emirates Dirham </option>
<option value="ARS"> ARS - Argentine Peso </option>
...
```

I do not have access to the html code and I want to display only the first 3 letters of the select.

I want the result to be:

```
<option value="EUR">EUR</option>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this :

```
$('option').html(function(_, html) {
   return html.split('-')[0].trim()
});
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3BZUL/)**

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK, I'll comply.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (*as you already have first three char's as value*)

```
$('option').each(function(){
   $(this).text($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: this works just fine. but I do not understand why .text and val() leaves the 3 characters. can you explain?

Comment: @Pr3tor .. .text or .val() is not leaving those three characters.. we are just using the option's value as it's text.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('option').each(function(){
   $(this).text($(this).text().split('-')[0]);
})
```